# ifstream fails to open a file when it is in the correct location

Tags: c++

I am opening the file like so...

```
ifstream file("testing.txt", ios::in);
if (file.is_open()) {
    cout << "opened!";
}
else {
    cout << "failed!";
}
```

The file location is as so...
`source -> repos -> TempStuff -> FirstStuff -> testing.txt`
My solution is `TempStuff` and the cpp file is `FirstStuff`. The file does not open, and I am not sure why.

Comment: What is the working directory? You can try and use strace to see where your program looks for the file.

Comment: I'm very new to c++. How do I see the working directory and use strace?

Comment: Something like strace -e trace=open your_program. In general see 'man strace'.

Comment: What IDE are you using? Most likely, your current working directory is different than the directory containing `"testing.txt"`. For simple programs, compiling from the command line eliminates all IDE config issues and lets you compile as many different programs without having to set up individual projects in an IDE -- something to consider.

Comment: The default _working directory_ is not necessarily the same as the executable directory - that is platform/environment dependent but will normally be the directory from which the executable was launched, which in your IDE may be `TempStuff` for example.  You might add code to set the working directory to the executable directory, but in an installation where you don't have write permission to the installation directory, that will itself cause problems.  Your IDE may allow you to set the working directory in the debug settings - but that is only of help in the IDE.

Comment: The IDE is Visual Studio. Giving the absolute path did indeed fix the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please change your path as Absolute Path.
Currently your file_path is ./testing.txt. Searching the file testing.txt in your current working directory(where your cpp file was available)
By changing your path to absolute path(./source/repos/TempStuff/FirstStuff/testing.txt).you will get your file open.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    ifstream file("./source/repos/TempStuff/FirstStuff/testing.txt", ios::in);
    if (file.is_open()) {
        cout << "opened!";
    }
    else {
    cout << "failed!";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Use absolute path to the file to make sure that permissions are not the cause of the problem.
2. If use of absolute path works, then startup directory of your program is different than the directory where the file exists. Update the startup directory in your IDE's settings.